# RTT to TEXTURE_BUFFER

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

In a RenderToTexture context, with several shaders involved, I need CPU access to one of the final render targets. Using `glGetTexImage` works great, unfortunately it copies all texture data to client memory.

In order to avoid this copy, I am trying to implemnet a RTT using a `TEXTURE_BUFFER`, hence attaching a separate Buffer Object to a texture, using that texture as part of the rendering, and then simply use `glMapBuffer` to map the texture's datastore and make it accessible to the CPU.

Apart from the code, I would like to ask if such strategy may be right (nothing better crosses my mind) or if it goes against any specification.

I have tons of documents regarding TBOs as a way to setup textures, but nothing regarding the use of TBOs for reading the result of an RTT. I am just wondering if what I am trying to do is not legal in any way.

Comment: why you need to download the content to the system memory? maybe you could do the work on the gpu? mapping buffer will usually make a copy as well. https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping

Comment: Im actually trying to avoid copying to system memory. Mapping a buffer object often resolves with no copy involved. No, cant work on the GPU

Comment: you can also take a look at pixel buffer objects http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html, https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object

Comment: Yes I thought about PBOs, unfortunately here there is little gain in managing asyncronous transfers, since I need the content of the texture right after the rendering; thats why Im trying to avoid any form od copy. I _did_ write my implementation of buffered RTT, but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: seems like `glFramebufferTexture2D` doesnt like having a `TEXTURE_BUFFER` as a color attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this approach won't work. A [buffer texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) is not really an oridinary 2D texture that can be used as render target or for 2D texture filtering, as described in [this related question/answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6281342/743214). It is really just a buffer's data made accessible to a shader as a **linear 1D integer-indexed array** (disguised as a special kind of texture) and thus doesn't have much to do with an ordinary filtered 2D texture. It is much more similar to what OpenGL 4 later introduced as a [shader storage buffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) (but in a more cumbersome and read-only way, yet available on GL 3 hardware), or a [uniform buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) (but with a larger size and using a different memory region). So no, you cannot use a TBO as a render target in an FBO.

What might be an option for you would be a [pixel buffer object (PBO)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object). While this would still involve a copy from texture memory into an additional buffer, if used right you could still profit from stuff like asynchronous reading, special host-accessible memory and such things.

Comment: Thanks. After more in-depth considerations I decided to go for PBOs as suggested at first by Fen, and modifying the rendering pipeline so to maximize asynchronous operations.